# entity framework error there is already an object with that name available in the database

Tags: entity-framework

I am using the Entity Framework POCOs to assist with migrating data from a legacy database to a new database. Both databases already exist and the Entity Framework has no part in creating or modifying structure for either.  I created a sample database on the migration server and restored it to my local computer sql server (entirely in t_sql, no EF) and my context and its data classes are working fine and returning the data I want.  Today I went to the production migration server and when I go to run my first test I get the above referenced error.

All I am doing is reading data, no writing, so this makes no sense to me.  EF must be doing something when it hooks up the data context that I can't see. The error is coming from SqlClient.SqlConnection.  There is no inner exception, no help link and nothing in the call stack except my method

Any ideas where to start looking?
Pamela

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the Entity Framework gets mad when the database changes at any point.  You need to tell it to ignore the database.  I did it by creating this base class for my data contexts

```
enter code here    public class BaseContext<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected BaseContext()
        : base("Foxpert.HS.ChangeDetection.VHSContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null);
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }
}
```